# How to Never Have Linewraps no Matter What in a Div with a Fixed Width and Overflow Set to Auto

Tags: css, die

I give up. Okay? I give up. I don't want to parade around with showing off code. I have spent *three and a half months* searching and experimenting CSS codes across the Internet. The only place left to check is the dark web. I don't care what your end game is here. I give up.

Please, just tell me how to get these lines to stop breaking, no matter what the case may be. If you can't, you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It would be lovely to see your code, but it seems what you want is CSS [white-space](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/)

Specifically, `white-space: nowrap`

That should do what it appears you are asking for.